# Uncaught TypeError: this.paramSend is not a function

Tags: javascript, polymer

I need help with this error, I need to pass the values ​​of "id1"
and "roll" that I am assigning them in the addEventListener, to the param  send function.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.paramSend is not a function

```
<script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'pa-adminuser',
        properties: {
          id1: {
            type: String,
            value: '0',
            notify: true
          },
          hide: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: true
          },
          roll: {
            type: String,
            value: '0',
            notify: true
          }
        },
        aftersave: function(){
          this.$.themed.addEventListener('after-save', function(e) {
              this.id1= e.detail.row.id;
              this.roll= e.detail.row.roll;
              console.log('paramSend1:' + JSON.stringify({ id: this.id1, roll: this.roll }));
              this.paramSend(this.id1, this.roll)
          });
        },
        paramSend: function(id2, roll2){
          this.PostData1.body = JSON.stringify({ id: id2, roll: roll2 });
          this.PostData1.generateRequest();
          this._updateData();
        },
        _updateData: function() {
          console.log('UPDATE DATA');
          this.async(function() {
            //this.$.PostData1.generateRequest();
            this.$.GetData3.generateRequest();
            console.log('GENERATE REQUEST');
          }, 2000);
        },
        ready: function() {
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your eventHandler to preserve your this context.

```
this.$.themed.addEventListener('after-save', function(e) {
  ....
  this.paramSend( .. )
}.bind(this) );
```

Or use a local this ref.

```
var _self = this;
this.$.themed.addEventListener('after-save', function(e) {
  ....
  _self.paramSend( .. )
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with the two options I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution this way, I hope someone helps

```
aftersave: function(){
          var _self = this;
          this.$.themed.addEventListener('after-save', function(e) {
              _self.id1= e.detail.row.id;
              _self.roll= e.detail.row.roll;
              console.log('paramSend1:' + JSON.stringify({ id: this.id1, roll: this.roll }));              
              _self.paramBody = JSON.stringify({ id: this.id1, roll: this.roll });
              _self.$.PostData1.body = _self.paramBody;
              _self.$.PostData1.generateRequest();  
          });
        },
```